# Asana API Returning a 500 error when attempting to update due_on

Tags: php, api, rest, asana

I am building a new app in PHP which will allow me to use CSV templates to import task-heavy projects with due dates and asignees in place.  Thus far, I have managed to get it working for everything except the due_on field.  Whenever I included due_on in the request body, regardless of whether it is in the first POST request to create the task or a subsequent PUT request to update the task, a 500 Error is being returned.

On task update, for instance, I am hitting https://api.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/*task-id* with a put request, and am passing the following request body through, using the Chrome Advanced REST client:

```
{"data":{"due_on":"2012-06-01"}}
```

This is returned:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Server Error","phrase":"12 small pandas eat briefly"}]}
```

Is there something in the syntax of my put request, or the format of my date which would be causing this? Passing the same values via PHP directly also seem to cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

(I work for Asana)

You are not doing anything wrong - it appears as though you've uncovered a bug in the API that's eluded our unit tests. Thanks for reporting this! We've pushed a fix so it should be working now.

Comment: We've pushed a fix, so this should be working now. Some of the servers may be lagging and running the older code, so you might see this error come up occasionally, but that should stop shortly.